# PfSense architecture for small business data center

Tags: networking, server, juju, maas, firewall

Project is to collocate a Small DataCenter Structure (locally for development and Hosting purpose (WebServer)) behind PFsense Firewalls. We got some HP DL360 G5's ready to use for this, so ahead to the project's structure I intend to build:

1. **Internet Provider Modem/Router**
2. **Pfsense Firewall:**
   3x Pfsense for main Security use + 3 Mirroring of main PFsense Firewalls by Fail.
3. **Ubuntu MaaS DC Structure** (incl Juju, etc.)**:** 1x Region Controller + 2x Rack Controller for 2x separate Rack Server Units.

My plan is to build a multiple firewall with PFsense. I hope the logical architecture is correct:

```
                              Provider Router/Modem
                                         |
            PFs1---------------------------------------------------PFs1m
             |                                                        |
            PFs2---------------------------------------------------PFs2m  
             |                                                        |
            PFs3---------------------------------------------------PFs3m
                                         |
                              MaaS Region Controller
                                         /\
                                        /  \
                                       /    \
    MaaS Rack Controller---------------      -----------------MaaS Rack Controller  
      /           \                                            /          \
    Nodes         Nodes                                      Nodes        Nodes
```

Legend:
PFs{number}  = PFsense
PFs{number}m = PFsense (mirror for HA)

Is it possible to use multiple PFsense Firewalls to "improve" security with more Firewalls behind?
How to do that?

Comment: Your question is too broad asking how to build a physical architecture is broad enough, "is CARP for PFsense Firewall a good solution?" is asking for an opinion, "How you would suggest to configure the whole project?" - very broad question, and finally "Experience Sharing and Interest Article to read?" not really sure what you are asking here.

Comment: @karel, no no it's fine... didn't ment to rework it the way you did... thought just to add some Updates... but the way you've reworked it, it's fine... I woudl suggest to forghet the Physical Achritectual structure... due in DataCenters it's widely done by most practical way, and it depends on location... to many factors that influences decisions... so i will fix the question in next edit. Thanks a lot

Comment: I don't see how a question about dedicated firewalls may be related to Ubuntu. Your question is off topic. Nonetheless I'm voting to reopen because it's no longer too broad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this question is YES, you can!

CARP is the Best Method for this use.

You can configure as many Firewalls as you want. All you're going to do is Mirroring the first Firewall as a clone.
Example:
you get 3 Firewalls (FW1, FW2, FW3)

FW1 is the main 0
FW2 is clone of 1
FW3 is clone of 2

So if:
1: FW1 is UP -> FW2 is UP -> FW3 is UP = FW1 is running (FW2 + FW3 as clone)
2: FW1 is DOWN -> FW2 is UP -> FW3 is UP = FW2 is running (FW3 as clone)
3: FW1 is DOWN -> FW2 is DOWN -> FW3 is UP = FW3 is running (no clone)
4: FW1 is UP -> FW2 is DOWN/UP -> FW3 is DOWN/UP = FW1 is running (FW2 + FW3 as clone)
.
.
.
and so on.

Search around for CARP+PFSense+Ubuntu as well on PFSense forums around.